# DeclerationError:Function with same name and parameter types defined twice solicity .deps/npm/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Tags: token, cryptocurrency, erc20, remix-ide, cryptocurrency-token

Hi I am currently building a ERC20 token on remix and I ran into an error where it said DeclerationError:Function with same name and parameter types defined twice .deps/npm/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

This is my code

> 

````
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v5.0.0) (token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {IERC20} from "./IERC20.sol";
import {IERC20Metadata} from "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import {Context} from "../../utils/Context.sol";
import {IERC20Errors} from "../../interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol";

/**
 * @dev Implementation of the {IERC20} interface.
 *
 * This implementation is agnostic to the way tokens are created. This means
 * that a supply mechanism has to be added in a derived contract using {_mint}.
 *
 * TIP: For a detailed writeup see our guide
 * https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-implement-erc20-supply-mechanisms/226[How
 * to implement supply mechanisms].
 *
 * The default value of {decimals} is 18. To change this, you should override
 * this function so it returns a different value.
 *
 * We have followed general OpenZeppelin Contracts guidelines: functions revert
 * instead returning `false` on failure. This behavior is nonetheless
 * conventional and does not conflict with the expectations of ERC20
 * applications.
 *
 * Additionally, an {Approval} event is emitted on calls to {transferFrom}.
 * This allows applications to reconstruct the allowance for all accounts just
 * by listening to said events. Other implementations of the EIP may not emit
 * these events, as it isn't required by the specification.
 */
abstract contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata, IERC20Errors {
    mapping(address account => uint256) private _balances;

    uint256 public buyFee = 5;
    uint256 public sellFee = 5;

    mapping(address account => mapping(address spender => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping(address account => bool) private _isPair;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    /**
     * @dev Sets the values for {name} and {symbol}.
     *
     * All two of these values are immutable: they can only be set once during
     * construction.
     */
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }


    function addPair(address pair, bool value) internal {
        _isPair[pair] = value;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the name of the token.
     */
    function name() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the symbol of the token, usually a shorter version of the
     * name.
     */
    function symbol() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the number of decimals used to get its user representation.
     * For example, if `decimals` equals `2`, a balance of `505` tokens should
     * be displayed to a user as `5.05` (`505 / 10 ** 2`).
     *
     * Tokens usually opt for a value of 18, imitating the relationship between
     * Ether and Wei. This is the default value returned by this function, unless
     * it's overridden.
     *
     * NOTE: This information is only used for _display_ purposes: it in
     * no way affects any of the arithmetic of the contract, including
     * {IERC20-balanceOf} and {IERC20-transfer}.
     */
    function decimals() public view virtual returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-totalSupply}.
     */
    function totalSupply() public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-balanceOf}.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transfer}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - the caller must have a balance of at least `value`.
     */
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _transfer(owner, to, value);
        return true;
    }
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }


    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require (sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient !=address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 _buyFee = amount.mul(buyFee).div(100);
        uint256 _sellFee = amount.mul(sellFee).div(100);

        if (_isPair[sender]) {
            amount = amount.sub(_buyFee);
            _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(_buyFee, "ERC20: Transfer amount exceeds balance");
            _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].add(_buyFee);
            emit Transfer(sender,address(this),_buyFee);
        }

        if (_isPair[recipient]) {
            amount = amount.sub(_sellFee);
            _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(_sellFee, "ERC20: Transfer amount exceeds balance");
            _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].add(_sellFee);
            emit Transfer(sender,address(this),_sellFee);
        }

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20 transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender,recipient,amount);

    }


    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-allowance}.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-approve}.
     *
     * NOTE: If `value` is the maximum `uint256`, the allowance is not updated on
     * `transferFrom`. This is semantically equivalent to an infinite approval.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transferFrom}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance. This is not
     * required by the EIP. See the note at the beginning of {ERC20}.
     *
     * NOTE: Does not update the allowance if the current allowance
     * is the maximum `uint256`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `from` and `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `from` must have a balance of at least `value`.
     * - the caller must have allowance for ``from``'s tokens of at least
     * `value`.
     */
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address spender = _msgSender();
        _spendAllowance(from, spender, value);
        _transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Moves a `value` amount of tokens from `from` to `to`.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to {transfer}, and can be used to
     * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     *
     * NOTE: This function is not virtual, {_update} should be overridden instead.
     */
    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
        if (from == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
        }
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        _update(from, to, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers a `value` amount of tokens from `from` to `to`, or alternatively mints (or burns) if `from`
     * (or `to`) is the zero address. All customizations to transfers, mints, and burns should be done by overriding
     * this function.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _update(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal virtual {
        if (from == address(0)) {
            // Overflow check required: The rest of the code assumes that totalSupply never overflows
            _totalSupply += value;
        } else {
            uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
            if (fromBalance < value) {
                revert ERC20InsufficientBalance(from, fromBalance, value);
            }
            unchecked {
                // Overflow not possible: value <= fromBalance <= totalSupply.
                _balances[from] = fromBalance - value;
            }
        }

        if (to == address(0)) {
            unchecked {
                // Overflow not possible: value <= totalSupply or value <= fromBalance <= totalSupply.
                _totalSupply -= value;
            }
        } else {
            unchecked {
                // Overflow not possible: balance + value is at most totalSupply, which we know fits into a uint256.
                _balances[to] += value;
            }
        }

        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Creates a `value` amount of tokens and assigns them to `account`, by transferring it from address(0).
     * Relies on the `_update` mechanism
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
     *
     * NOTE: This function is not virtual, {_update} should be overridden instead.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 value) internal {
        if (account == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        _update(address(0), account, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys a `value` amount of tokens from `account`, lowering the total supply.
     * Relies on the `_update` mechanism.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * NOTE: This function is not virtual, {_update} should be overridden instead
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 value) internal {
        if (account == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
        }
        _update(account, address(0), value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets `value` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner` s tokens.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
     * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `owner` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     *
     * Overrides to this logic should be done to the variant with an additional `bool emitEvent` argument.
     */
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        _approve(owner, spender, value, true);
    }

      

    /**
     * @dev Variant of {_approve} with an optional flag to enable or disable the {Approval} event.
     *
     * By default (when calling {_approve}) the flag is set to true. On the other hand, approval changes made by
     * `_spendAllowance` during the `transferFrom` operation set the flag to false. This saves gas by not emitting any
     * `Approval` event during `transferFrom` operations.
     *
     * Anyone who wishes to continue emitting `Approval` events on the`transferFrom` operation can force the flag to
     * true using the following override:
     * ```
     * function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value, bool) internal virtual override {
     *     super._approve(owner, spender, value, true);
     * }
     * ```
     *
     * Requirements are the same as {_approve}.
     */
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value, bool emitEvent) internal virtual {
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidApprover(address(0));
        }
        if (spender == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSpender(address(0));
        }
        _allowances[owner][spender] = value;
        if (emitEvent) {
            emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Updates `owner` s allowance for `spender` based on spent `value`.
     *
     * Does not update the allowance value in case of infinite allowance.
     * Revert if not enough allowance is available.
     *
     * Does not emit an {Approval} event.
     */
    function _spendAllowance(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal virtual {
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
        if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) {
            if (currentAllowance < value) {
                revert ERC20InsufficientAllowance(spender, currentAllowance, value);
            }
            unchecked {
                _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - value, false);
            }
        }
    }
     
}
````

The code thats affected is

> 

```
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }


    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require (sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient !=address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 _buyFee = amount.mul(buyFee).div(100);
        uint256 _sellFee = amount.mul(sellFee).div(100);

        if (_isPair[sender]) {
            amount = amount.sub(_buyFee);
            _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(_buyFee, "ERC20: Transfer amount exceeds balance");
            _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].add(_buyFee);
            emit Transfer(sender,address(this),_buyFee);
        }

        if (_isPair[recipient]) {
            amount = amount.sub(_sellFee);
            _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(_sellFee, "ERC20: Transfer amount exceeds balance");
            _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].add(_sellFee);
            emit Transfer(sender,address(this),_sellFee);
        }

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20 transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender,recipient,amount);

    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? If so please let me know as soon as possible